# To derive a test for comparing means of normal distribution when type 1 and type 2 errors are specified.

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, normal-distribution

> A normal population has standard deviation 16. The critical region for testing $H_0: \mu=5$ versus the alternative $H_1: \mu=k$ is $\bar{X}>k-2$. What should be the value of the constant $k$ and the sample size $n$ which would allow the probability of the type I error to be 0.0228 and the probability of the type II error to be 0.1587.

---

This is what I have done so far.

Type 1 error is the probability of rejecting the null hypothesis when it is true. Now if the null hypothesis is true i.e $\mu=5$, then $\frac{\sqrt{n}(\bar{X}-5)}{\sigma} \sim N(0,1)$. But we want the probability of the rejection region to be 0.0228 and $z_{0.0228}=2$.

$$\begin{align}
\frac{(\bar{X}-5)}{\sigma}>2\\
\implies \frac{(\bar{X}-5)}{16}>2\\
\implies \bar{X}>\frac{32}{\sqrt{n}}+5
\end{align}$$

Comparing this with the test  $\bar{X}>k-2$ we can conclude that $k-2=\frac{32}{\sqrt{n}}+5$

If I repeat the same argument for Type 2 error which is probability of accepting null hypothesis when it is not true i.e when alternative hypothesis is true, we have

$$\begin{align}
\frac{(\bar{X}-k)}{\sigma}>z_{0.1587}\\
\implies \frac{(\bar{X}-k)}{16}>1\\
\implies \bar{X}>\frac{16}{\sqrt{n}}+k
\end{align}$$

But $k-2=\frac{16}{\sqrt{n}}+k$ makes no sense.

Where am I going wrong? Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks.